# Heap corruption detected - iPhone 5S only

Tags: ios, objective-c, audio, core-audio

I am developing an app that listens for frequency/pitches, it works fine on iPhone4s, simulator and others but not iPhone 5S. This is the message I am getting:

```
malloc: *** error for object 0x178203a00: Heap corruption detected, free list canary is damaged
```

Any suggestion where should I start to dig into?

Thanks!

Comment: The corruption is probably on a devices it just was detected on the 5s. Search around for the malloc_debug library that you can use to find your problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The iPhone 5s has an arm64/64-bit CPU.  Check all the analyze compiler warnings for trying to store 64-bit pointers (and other values) into 32-bit C data types.

Also make sure all your audio code parameter passing, object messaging, and manual memory management code is thread safe, and meets all real-time requirements.

Answer (score 2):

In case it helps anyone, I had exactly the same problem as described above.

The cause in my particular case was pthread_create(pthread_t* thread, ...) on ARM64 was putting the value into *thread at some time AFTER the thread was started. On OSX, ARM32 and on the simulator, it was consistently filling in this value before the start_routine was called.

If I performed a pthread_detach operation in the running thread before that value was written (even by using pthread_self() to get the current thread_t), I would end up with the heap corruption message.

I added a small loop in my thread dispatcher that waited until that value was filled in -- after which the heap errors went away. Don't forget 'volatile'!

Restructuring the code might be a better way to fix this -- it depends on your situation. (I noticed this in a unit test that I'd written, I didn't trip up on this issue on any 'real' code)

Answer (score 0):

Same problem. but my case is I malloc 10Byte memory, but I try to use 20Byte. then it Heap corruption.

```
@@ -64,7 +64,7 @@ char* bytesToHex(char* buf, int size) {
         * be converted to two hex characters, also add an extra space for the terminating
         * null byte.
         * [size] is the size of the buf array */
-       int len = (size * 2) + 1;
+       int len = (size * 3) + 1;
        char* output = (char*)malloc(len * sizeof(char));
        memset(output, 0, len);
        /* pointer to the first item (0 index) of the output array */
    char *ptr = &output[0];
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        /* "sprintf" converts each byte in the "buf" array into a 2 hex string
         * characters appended with a null byte, for example 10 => "0A\0".
         *
         * This string would then be added to the output array starting from the
         * position pointed at by "ptr". For example if "ptr" is pointing at the 0
         * index then "0A\0" would be written as output[0] = '0', output[1] = 'A' and
         * output[2] = '\0'.
         *
         * "sprintf" returns the number of chars in its output excluding the null
         * byte, in our case this would be 2. So we move the "ptr" location two
         * steps ahead so that the next hex string would be written at the new
         * location, overriding the null byte from the previous hex string.
         *
         * We don't need to add a terminating null byte because it's been already
         * added for us from the last hex string. */
        ptr += sprintf(ptr, "%02X ", buf[i] & 0xFF);
    }
    return output;
```